# How to use rowwise values as part of summarise in dplyr, achieving a similar behavior to data.table?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Issue best explained using an example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2),
  x = 1:4
)
```

Let's say we need to get a mean by group, multiplied by group value. In `data.table` this works straightforwardly and intuitively.

```
> setDT(df)[, .(mean(x) * id), by=id]
   id  V1
1:  1 1.5
2:  2 7.0
```

In `dplyr` however, there is a warning and row duplication.

```
> df |> group_by(id) |> summarise(mean(x) * id)
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 4 × 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id `mean(x) * id`
  <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1            1.5
2     1            1.5
3     2            7  
4     2            7  
Warning message:
Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
```

I realise I can get rid of duplication by adding an extra step of `unique()`, but can't help feeling that `dplyr` isn't being used as it should in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cur_group()` to get the current group information. Then extract the ID from there

```
df |> summarise(mean(x) * cur_group()$id, .by=id)
#   id mean(x) * cur_group()$id
# 1  1                      1.5
# 2  2                      7.0
```

If you had more grouping columns, you could do

```
df <- data.frame(alpha = c(7,7,23,23), beta=c(-1,-1,3,3), x = 1:4)

df |> group_by(alpha, beta) |> summarise(mean(x) * cur_group()$alpha)
#  alpha  beta `mean(x) * cur_group()$alpha`
#   <dbl> <dbl>                         <dbl>
# 1     7    -1                          10.5
# 2    23     3                          80.5
df |> group_by(alpha, beta) |> summarise(mean(x) * cur_group()$beta)
#   alpha  beta `mean(x) * cur_group()$beta`
#   <dbl> <dbl>                        <dbl>
# 1     7    -1                         -1.5
# 2    23     3                         10.5
```

Comment: `df |> group_by(alpha, beta) |> summarise(a = mean(x) * cur_group()$alpha, b = mean(x) * cur_group()$beta)` also works with more groups.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use the grouping variable, we have to use `cur_group_id()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
    summarise(v1 = mean(x) * cur_group_id(), .by = id)

  id  v1
1  1 1.5
2  2 7.0
```

Comment: Note that `cur_group_id()` will assign new IDs to each group. You'd get the same answer even if you had `df <- data.frame(id = c(7,7,23,23),x = 1:4)`

Comment: I think you are right, MrFlick, I would have to extract the id column actual values, as in your excelent answer. I will delete this one